# Why doesn't img reach to the bottom of its containing div?

Tags: css

Notice that the bottom of the image does not reach the red outline below it, which is the bottom of the containing div.

What's going on here? This is counter-intuitive or not obvious to me anyway.

I'm not looking for a kludge to fix it. This is a made up example. I'm trying to master my understanding of css.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.frame {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0px;
}
.frame img {
  /*border: 10px solid yellow;
  outline: 10px solid blue;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/city/200x300/" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are inline elements and are, thus, treated like text. They sit on the baseline just as text does so there is a slight padding underneath them. That gap is there to allow for descenders of text.

To remove the gap, add `vertical-align:bottom` to the CSS for the image.

Comment: Wow! Now THAT is what I call counter-intuitive! Thanks bro!

Comment: Up voted for good explanation. So, let me ask you a follow-up question, if I may. Why would I ever want to treat an image like text? If there's a url of a page that uses it that way, or what web developers call that technique, if that makes any sense?

Comment: @toddmo You should think of it as being set as an inline element, not text, though I worded it that way cause text is inline, too. Technically not correct cause text is contained inside a line box but now I'll be getting too wordy and broad. For an explanation, you should read the spec itself: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting

Answer (score 2):

In order to get rid of this, just add this style to your `<img>`:

```
    display: block
```

This will force the image display not to be inline and so that things like `line-height` won't apply to it.

Comment: Can you think of any reason why I would ever NOT want to use `display: block` on an `img`? I'm not seeing the point of ever letting one be `inline`. Thanks.

Comment: An icon might be useful to be let `inline`, usually it follows some text